# Anti de-Sitter Geodesics

Tags: geodesics, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Timelike geodesics in anti de-Sitter space cannot reach infinity. I believe this has something to do with Clairaut's relation. I'm pretty sure it's true though as the analogy with conservation of angular momentum when traveling along a surface of revolution makes sense (see comments in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273108/tikz-geodesics-on-various-shapes/273129#273129)!

For AdS, we will be talking about a one-sheeted hyperboloid, we require that $r \cos{\theta}$ is kept constant where according to Wikipedia definition of Clairaut's relation, at a point $P$ on the geodesic, $r$ is the radius of the parallel circle through $P$ and $\theta$ is the angle the geodesic makes with this circle at the point $P$.

We immediately see that if the initial values are $r_*$ and $\theta_*$ then $r_* \cos{\theta_*}=R_*$ is constant and because cosine is bounded, the geodesic can never cross a circle of radius $R_*$ i.e. we hit a turning point. How does this turning point work? If $r$ is increasing then $\cos{\theta}$ must be decreasing and this will cause $\theta$ to increase whereas we really want it to decrease to $\theta=0$ which indicates a turning point, right?
Secondly, what happens for null and spacelike geodesics since these are able to reach infinity! How is this consistent with Clairaut's relation? In order to be able to get $r \rightarrow \infty$, I've concluded that $\cos{\theta}=0$ everywhere i.e. $\theta=90^\circ$ everywhere. But this doesn't seem right since this is when the geodesic is perpendicular to a circle through $P$ and that would only happen if we travel along a meridian of the hyperboloid (a very specific and extreme case of a spacelike geodesic). We should be able to reach infinity for any spacelike or null geodesic but I cannot see how this would be consistent?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For those of us without access (due to work-related regulatory policies), could you just copy the text of the comment?

Comment: @KyleKanos "geodesics do not asymptote to the generating curve, they turn around when the radius gets small, corresponding to conservation of angular momentum (Clairaut's relation)."
Hope that helps :)